# storybook + nextjs router: NextContext.Provider is undefined, please add it to parameters.nextRouter.Provider

Tags: next.js, storybook, next-router

I'm really fighting to get storybook, and nextjs router to play together. I'm getting the following error:

> NextContext.Provider is undefined, please add it to
> parameters.nextRouter.Provider

I've setup a nextjs + storybook project. Now I have a component which uses `useRouter`. I have followed [the official guideline](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-next-router/). This is my `main.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-essentials', 
    'storybook-addon-next-router'
  ]
};
```

And this is my `preview.js` file:

```
import { RouterContext } from "next/dist/next-server/lib/router-context";

export const parameters = {
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
  },
}
```

When I preview the storybook and navigate to my component, I get the error:

```
NextContext.Provider is undefined, please add it to parameters.nextRouter.Provider
```

I can't figure out what else I should do. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What version of next are you using?

Answer (score 7):

You will need to add it to your [Global Parameters](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/parameters#global-parameters) in **preview.js** like so:

```
// .storybook/preview.js

import { RouterContext } from "next/dist/shared/lib/router-context";

// ... 

export const parameters = {
  nextRouter: {
    Provider: RouterContext.Provider,
    locale: "en" // optional
  },
};
```